# Problems creatings Pods with kubernetes and YAML

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

I'm newbie with K8s and trying to create multiple Pods using a **.yml** file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: pod-test1
    labels:
        app: frontend
        env: dev
spec:
    containers:
    -   name: container1
        image: nginx:alpine

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: pod-test2
    labels:
        app: backend
        env: dev
spec:
    containers:
    -   name: container2
        image: nginx:alpine
```

But executing `kubectl apply -f label.yml`, is creating just the second Pod:
[image]

Could someone give a hint of why this is happening, and if is possible a brief explanation, please?

Thanks a lot, best regards.

Answer (score 4):

use `---` as seperator between two resources in yaml file like following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: pod-test1
    labels:
        app: frontend
        env: dev
spec:
    containers:
    -   name: container1
        image: nginx:alpine
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: pod-test2
    labels:
        app: backend
        env: dev
spec:
    containers:
    -   name: container2
        image: nginx:alpine
```

Comment: @DiegoNieto would consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem?